# What is the best way to iterate through the member's value of every object present in a list..?

Tags: python, loops, class, object

I've a list `x=[obj1,obj2,obj3]`
each of the objects has a member called `IDobj`.

Now `tempObj` is a obj like `IDobj`.

I need to find if the `tempObj` is same of any `IDobj` of the objects present in the list `x`.

Note: need a shortest line of code by using Python functions like lambda, filter, itertools, etc.

I can write the code in simple logic without using the functions:

```
temp=[]
for i in x :
    temp.append(i.IDobj)
if tempObj in temp:
    print("found")
```

Comment: Is tempObj an attribute of the elements in the list? Or is it a separate variable?

Comment: Why do you need the shortest line? Write something that works, then worry about whether it come be improved.

Comment: need a shortest line code. Show us some code will try to shorten for you

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 yes it is. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @chepner Please check. I've added a code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `any`, as shown below

```
if any(obj.IDobj == tempObj for obj in list_x):
    print("found")
```